# How to force spring to do not zip log files, instead append date at end of log file

Tags: spring-boot, logging, log4j2

Currently I'm using spring boot logs and I'm configuring it through property file
below are the sample logging property

```
spring.main.banner-mode=off
logging.level.root= INFO,ERROR,DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework.web= ERROR
logging.level.com.concretepage= DEBUG 
logging.pattern.console=
logging.file = D://logTest.log
logging.file.max-size=100MB
spring.output.ansi.enabled=ALWAYS
```

The problem is that log file backup format is in .gz format
like **logTest.log.2019-06-14.0.gz**

How do I exclude default zipping ?

I don't want to hard wire configuration in xml file and put it inside resource folder. 
I can only put rolling appender configuration xml file, but I want to make logging file path in property file, So I can dynamically set it for different environment.

Is there any way to achieve this configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a logback-spring.xml file in src/main/resources

With this content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>

<appender name="FILE"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${FILE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <file>${LOG_FILE}</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <cleanHistoryOnStart>${LOG_FILE_CLEAN_HISTORY_ON_START:-false}</cleanHistoryOnStart>
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_FILE}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>${LOG_FILE_MAX_SIZE:-10MB}</maxFileSize>
            <maxHistory>${LOG_FILE_MAX_HISTORY:-7}</maxHistory>
            <totalSizeCap>${LOG_FILE_TOTAL_SIZE_CAP:-0}</totalSizeCap>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

</configuration>
```

If the fileNamePattern don't end with gz (or any other compression format) logback will not compress the files.

Comment: Thanks @Simon. It worked. I just need to do minor correction for property file.
I have to remove this empty property **logging.pattern.console=**, And also need to remove **<file>${LOG_FILE}</file>** as I have already mentioned log file in property.

Answer (score 8):

As an alternative to @simon-martinelli's correct answer, if you did not wish to use a custom `logback-spring.xml` file, the Spring configuration parameter `logging.pattern.rolling-file-name` can be set in your `application.properties` or `application.yml` file.

For example, to disable the compression used, remove the `.gz` suffix from the default file name pattern (`${LOG_FILE}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.gz` as per https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-custom-log-configuration).

This would require the addition of the following element to the `application.yml` file:

```
logging:
  pattern:
    rolling-file-name: "${LOG_FILE}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i"
```

Or if you are using `application.properties`, it would be:

```
logging.pattern.rolling-file-name = ${LOG_FILE}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i
```

Comment: Your`application.properties` version works fine.
You should propably also add `.log` to the file like:
`${LOG_FILE}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log`

Comment: As of Spring Boot 2.4+, it is now `logging.logback.rollingpolicy.file-name-pattern`.  https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/25535#issuecomment-794717348